# .NET class allowing fast search

Tags: .net, performance, hash, dictionary

I'm looking for suitable .NET class that allows me to store a large number of custom records and then look for a record instance.
To be more concrete, the record class has 3 Properties and I will use alwas one of them to look for an instance. The ammount of instances to be stored will be up to 100.000.

I know about HastSetOf(MyRecord> used with custom IEqualityComarer. The propblem is that at the lookup operation I will know only one of the record's props and will actually need the other 2 prop values.

Should I need a DictionaryOf(string, Record) or is there a faster one?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Dictionary class. In this case, you'll need three Dictionaries: one for each property that you're indexing by. If the properties are not unique, you'll want to use a Lookup instead.

```
var entriesById = entries.ToDictionary(e => e.Id);
var entriesByCategoryId = entries.ToLookup(e => e.CategoryId);

Console.WriteLine(entriesById[42].ToString());
foreach(var entry in entriesByCategoryId[13])
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy (and probably not the most memory efficient) way is to store the records in 3 separate hash tables (`Dictionary`) (one for each property-pairing) and look the record up based on the property in question

Another way could be to use a 3-tuple as the key for the map (populated with the three properties in question) and use a custom comparator that only consideres the appropriate element in the 3-tuple based on the propety given for the look-up

If you can come up with an ordering between and within the three properties (e.g. lexical ordering), you could use that to store the records in a sorted map, and perform a binary search (which will be more efficient than a linear query of all elements to find the one you are looking for)

EDIT: added specific class name for clarification after comment pointed it out

Comment: To make the connection to .NET: `Dictionary` is the standard hashtable implementation for the .NET framework.